# How can i set attributes with soap in WCF / .net

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to make a soap server with the attribute OptIn in WCF / .net 4.0

This is my test code

```
[DataContract]
public class Relatie
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Emailadres{ get; set; }
}
```

This will give a result without the OptIn, what must i add or change to specify this option?

```
<Relatie>
    <EmailAdres OptIn="true">mail@domein.com</EmailAdres>
</Relatie>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible when using `DataContractSerializer` because it doesn't support XML attributes. You must use XML serializer instead:

```
public class Relatie
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool OptIn { get; set; }
}
```

And your operation contract, service contract or service implementation must be marked with `[XmlSerializerFormat]` attribute.